# What are the most important parameters to tune in a deep belief network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, scikit-learn, deep-belief-networks

I am trying to create a Deep Belief Network (DBF) for a binary classification problem. The [nolearn](http://nolearndocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dbn.html) package provides a good library for implementing them. I see that there are very many parameters to learn and tune a DBF.

The possible list of parameters are:

> 1. The number of hidden layers and the number of neurons in each.
> 2. Learning rate
> 3. learn_rate_decays - The number with which the learn_rate is multiplied after each epoch of fine-tuning.
> 4. Momentum
> 5. Number of epochs to train (with backprop).
> 6. learn_rates_pretrain – A list of learning rates for pretraining.
> 7. momentum_pretrain – Momentum for pre-training.
> 8. L2 costs per weight layer.
> 9. Dropouts per weight layer.
> 10. Momentum for pre-training.
> 11. L2 costs per weight layer, for pre-training.
> 12. Number of epochs to pre-train (with CDN).
> 13. Scale of the randomly initialized weights.
> 14. Number of nonzero incoming connections to a hidden unit.
> 15. Output activation function. (can be any of Sigmoid, Linear, Softmax)

Among these what are the most important parameters to tune? Do I have to tune all the parameters?

Comment: This is potentially a reasonable & non-software-specific question. However, I doubt anyone who doesn't use this software (what?) will read or be familiar w/ this. Can you make this (1) software-neutral, (2) self-contained, & (3) more intelligible?

Comment: @gung Thanks for looking into the question. Have modified the question.